# "Я один кто не знал, что вариантов у итогового теста два?"

Tags: прилагательные, существительные, пунктуация

1. **вариантов** или **варианта**? Или можно использовать обе вариации?
2. Нужна ли запятая перед **что**?
3. Можно ли использовать **один**, или грамматически верно использовать только **единственный**?
4. Нужна ли запятая перед **кто**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом - пример разговорного современного языка, на границе литературной нормы, однако есть работающие правила:

1. вариантов (множественное неопределённое, сопоставимое с неопределенным артиклем в западных языках, ср. "Есть ключи?" "Найдутся места?" и так далее). В приближенном к литературной норме возможно только "варианта", без указания на определенность-неопределенность (и(ли) очевидность-неочевидность).
2. Нужна (перед подчиненным компонентом сложносоставного сложноподчиненного предложения).
3. Допускаются оба варианта, в сниженном регистре также возможно "(Это) только я, кто..." и "Я (тут) один такой, кто...".
4. Нужна (перед союзным словом).

Answer (score 5):

По-русски мы говорим так:

> Интересно, я один не знал, что у теста два **варианта** (только я не знал, я единственный не знал )

Возможен вариант с инверсией

> ..., что **вариантов** у теста два.

"**Кто**" показывает, что это калька с иностранного языка. В русском —лишнее (redundant ). Запятые перед придаточными нужны.

Answer (score 5):

1. При имеющемся порядке слов - "**вариантов**"(... имеется вот сколько:) два. В случае же прямого указания количества требуется согласование с числительным:

> Я *один* (один *я*) не знал, что у итогового теста два **варианта**?

(the emphasized word is shown in italics)

2. Запятая нужна - для отделения *придаточного предложения*.

3/4. См. возможный вариант с "один" в п. 1; исходная фраза неверна (она сконструирована искусственно или переведена - по-русски так не говорят, "кто" здесь излишне). Возможен вариант с "единственный вместо "один":

> Я единственный не знал, что вариантов у итогового теста два?

Можно без того и другого:

> (Выходит,) только я не знал, что вариантов у итогового теста два?

Comment: Почему не говорят, если "кто" возможно для усиления / акцента на определенности перед глаголом? Ср.: "Он один, кто понял", "Она только одна, кто не сделала..." и т. д.

Comment: Эти выражения возможны только с заменой "один" на "единственный" - "один, кто" - не сочетается, носители языка так не говорят.

Comment: А почему только со словом "единственный", если его синоним - "один"?

Comment: В данном контексте это _не взаимозаменяемые_ слова. Для более очевидной иллюстрации - можно начать предложение без местоимения "он" (не в нём дело): "**Единственный, кто** понял, в чём дело - это Иван. [= остальные не поняли или больше никто не понял] Но нельзя заменить "единственный" на "один": "**Один, кто** понял, в чём дело - это Иван." Если искать в этом предложении смысл, то он будет другим: Иван - один из понявших, в чём дело, и ожидается, что в след за этим будет назван кто-то ещё (получилось незаконченное высказывание).

Comment: @Alex_ander, Вы ранее сказали, что носители языка не говорят "один, кто". К счастью или сожалению, они так говорят. Я носитель и я не видел в таком употреблении при простом общении никакого насилия над языком. Я в чём-то не прав?

Comment: Носитель носителю - рознь, иные носители и на телевидении говорят удручающие вещи.

Answer (score -2):

Кроме того, что, как тут уже сказали, **`кто`** в этом предложении звучит плеонастично, или неуклюже, для того, чтобы фраза звучала более по-русски его можно заменить на **`который`**

> Я один, который не знал..?